# Nonlinear Differential Equation for physics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to calculate an equation of motion and there was a differential equation I couldn't solve:
$$
\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+A\cos(\theta)=0 
$$
Does someone know how to solve it?

Comment: The solution to this equation can't be given in terms of elementary functions, it requires elliptic integrals. In the limit that $\theta$ is small however you can find such a solution. ALthough it looks similar to a pendulum equation to me

Comment: It can be solved approximately atleast for some intial conditions. For example if $\theta(0) \approx \frac{\pi}{2}$ then taking $\theta = \pi/2 + \delta\theta$ we get $\ddot{\delta\theta} - A\delta\theta \approx 0$ so if $A<0$ we have stable oscillations $\delta\theta \approx \sin(\sqrt{-A}t + \phi)$.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would substitute $\theta=\pi/2-y$ making the equation 
$$-\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+A \sin(y)=0 .$$
Secondly I would scale time according to the rule $t=x/\sqrt{A}$ (here I will assume that $A>0$). This will result in the simpler equation
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\sin(y) $$
The general solution to this equation, is similar (note the minus sign) to the one that appears in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102582/the-general-solution-of-y-sin-y):
$$y(x)=2\text{am}\left(c_1x +c_2\bigg|-\frac{1}{c_1^2}\right) $$
where am is the [Jacobi amplitude function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html), and $c_1,c_2$ are arbitrary constants. Undoing the substitutions, we obtain the solution of the original equation as $$\theta(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}-2\text{am}\left(c_1\sqrt{A} t +c_2\bigg|-\frac{1}{c_1^2}\right) .$$

Answer (score 0):

This is like duffing's equation ,for little value of $\theta$

$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+A\sin (\theta)=0$
to find solution :put $sin (\theta)=\theta-\dfrac{\theta^3}{3!} $

and equation becomes $\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+A(\theta-\dfrac{\theta^3}{3!})=0 $ so , you can turn $$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+A\sin (\theta)=0 \\into \\\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+A(1-\dfrac{\theta^2}{2!})=0$$ and solve numerically

Comment: If we wanted to solve this numerically why would we approximate it at all? Why not solve $\theta'' + A\cos\theta = 0$ directly?