# Two complicated ODE exercises

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I found two complicated exercises of differential ordinary equations and I no have idea how attack the problems. I tried basic staffs, substitutions and nothing.

1. $f'(x)^2=1+a^2\sin^2(f(x))$
2. $f'(x)^2+1= a^2\sin^2(f(x))$

where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is a constant.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

---

Remark: It is not a system of ODE.

Comment: Am I wrong or the two exercises are the same?

Comment: @Irddo: Isn't that the same problem, one just subtracted one from each side? Also, using the first item, take the square root of each side and you have a separable equation. Separate and integrate - what a nasty integral!

Comment: @Moo, it is not a system of ODE, I need to solve in each case separately. I will put a remark about it, thanks you.

Comment: @Gibbs, they are a little bit differents.

Comment: @Irddo no, they are not.

Comment: @Gibbs, I'm sorry, you are right. I fixed second equation. Thanks you.

Comment: @Irddo: When did say it was a system? The second equation was the same as the first. The rest of my comment stands for both variants, you can leave the square on one side, take square roots and then you have a separable equation.

Comment: @Moo, can you formulate an answer of one of them? I will appreciate.

Comment: $$
\texttt{DSolve[f'[x]^2 == 1 + a^2*Sin[f[x]]^2, f[x], x]}
$$
$$
\left\{\left\{f(x)\to -\text{am}\left(x-\sqrt{2} c_1|-a^2\right)\right\},\left\{f(x)\to \text{am}\left(x+c_1 \sqrt{2}|-a^2\right)\right\}\right\}
$$

Comment: @Irddo: $$f'(x) = \pm~ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 \sin^2(f(x))+1}}$$ Write $$\int \pm~ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 \sin^2(f(x))+1}}df(x) = \int 1~dx$$

Comment: @Math1000, solutions of Wolfram are not praticables. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Irddo do you need to find an exact expression of $f(x)$ or what else?

Comment: @Gibbs, yes, I need!

Comment: @Irddo I do not see how to avoid to use the Jacobi amplitude. For example, take the first equation and differentiate both sides. Then you end up with something like $y'' = C\sin 2y$. You can find several discussions on equations like this, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2102582/the-general-solution-of-y-sin-y).